# Codeigniter form validation set_checkbox()

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter form validation set_checkbox() function. I would like to keep the checkbox checked which are checked before submission and unchecked which are unchecked before submission. What should I do ??

Thanks

Comment: You want before submission or after submission?
I think after submission is your question correct?

Comment: @somasundaram  -- I want after sumission.

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheck[]" value="1" <?php echo set_checkbox('mycheck[]', '1'); ?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheck[]" value="2" <?php echo set_checkbox('mycheck[]', '2'); ?> />
```

Please refer this url : http://codeigniter.in.th/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: at the very end of that provided url.

Comment: @somasundaram -- I know the above code but my problem is about check and uncheck after submission.